# Undefined: byteReader error in Structex golang

Tags: go

I forked the https://github.com/HewlettPackard/structex, and tried to turn the example code which is :

```
    package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/HewlettPackard/structex"
)

type SCSI_Standard_Inquiry struct {
    PeripheralDeviceType uint8 `bitfield:"5"`          // Byte 0
    PeripheralQualifier  uint8 `bitfield:"3"`
    reserved0            uint8 `bitfield:"6,reserved"` // Byte 1
    LU_Cong              uint8 `bitfield:"1"`
    RMB                  uint8 `bitfield:"1"`
    Version              uint8                         // Byte 2
}

func main() {
    var inquiry = new(SCSI_Standard_Inquiry)

    // Perform IOCTL on device, returns byte reader to byte response

    if err := structex.Decode(byteReader, inquiry); err != nil {
        panic("a problem")
    }

    fmt.Printf("SCSI Peripheral Device Type: %d\n", inquiry.PeripheralDeviceType)
    fmt.Printf("SCSI Peripheral Qualifier: %d\n", inquiry.PeripheralQualifier)
    fmt.Printf("Inquiry Version: %#02x\n", inquiry.Version)
    // etc
}
```

, I am using sublime text with go build packages to build this code, i am getting the following error:
.\test.go:22:31: undefined: byteReader

Here is the function Decode for reference :

```
func Decode(reader io.ByteReader, s interface{}) error {

    d := decoder{
        reader:      reader,
        currentByte: 0,
        byteOffset:  0,
        bitOffset:   0,
    }

    t := newTranscoder(&d)
    d.transcoder = t

    return t.transcode(reflect.ValueOf(s), nil)
}

// DecodeByteBuffer takes a raw byte buffer and unpacks the buffer into
// the provided structure. Unused bytes do not cause an error.
func DecodeByteBuffer(b *bytes.Buffer, s interface{}) error {
    reader := byteBufferReader{
        buffer: b,
    }

    return Decode(&reader, s)
}
```

Comment: You forgot to implement this: `// Perform IOCTL on device, returns byte reader to byte response`.